# changing mySQL (5.6) database from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have recently upgraded my CPanel server from mySQL 5.5 to mySQL 5.6 as it now supports full-text searches for InnoDB. Now, I'm not so great at mySQL so I was wondering is there anything special I need to keep in mind other than running

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Several of my tables have full text indexes. What will happen to them? Will the indexes be automatically converted? Or do I have to re-build them manually afterwards?

Comment: When I did this conversion, I did a full dump and reload. Better to be safe than sorry...

Comment: ...but surely we *all* do regular backups anyway and we *always* verify them before attempting upgrades or schema changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not change any of the FULLTEXT startup parameters, your conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB will take care of creating the FULLTEXT indexes for InnoDB.

## CONVERSION STEPS

If you can connect to MySQL from a command-line interface, run this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_type='FULLTEXT';
```

This will give you every table that has a FULLTEXT index.

Using that query, run this query

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',B.table_schema,'.',B.table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB') Cmd
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name
FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE index_type='FULLTEXT') A
INNER JOIN information_schema.tables B USING (table_schema,table_name)
WHERE B.engine='MyISAM';
```

This will show you all the commands to convert MyISAM tables with FULLTEXT indexes into InnoDB.

You can dump the commands to a text file.

```
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',B.table_schema,'.',B.table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM (SELECT DISTINCT table_schema,table_name"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.statistics"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE index_type='FULLTEXT') A"
SQL="${SQL} INNER JOIN information_schema.tables B"
SQL="${SQL} USING (table_schema,table_name)"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE B.engine='MyISAM'"
mysql -uroot -p -ANe"${SQL}" > ConversionScript.sql
less ConversionScript.sql
```

This will create the conversion script and let you view it.

If you are satisfied with the content of the scripts, log in to mysql and run this:

```
mysql> source ConversionScript.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! :) I ran the first command successfully, but the 2nd gives me a syntax error saying "syntax error near unexpected token". Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot the word CONCAT. I'll fix it, BRB !!!

Comment: OK I just fixed it. Try it now !!!